# How to fully expand an org item's tree branch when visiting it from an agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

When I am in an org agenda view and use something like `org-agenda-goto` on an item, the org buffer is opened with a minimal tree expansion, with both parents and children concealed with `...` above and below. I could find no easy way to fully expand the branch without fully expanding the whole tree.

I would like to see the whole tree branch when I visit an item from the agenda. Preferably I would be able to control whether I only want to see parents or children fully expanded.

Is this possible with standard org mode, or does it require writing elisp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reveal more context around a given headline, use `org-reveal`.

To change the default context level, customize the variable `org-show-context-detail`. You can set different contexts to different visibility spans (or "detail levels"). Customize the `agenda` context and set its visibility span to `tree`.

Alternatively, set the `org-show-context-detail` variable to `t` in your .emacs and restart your emacs: that will set all contexts to have the "canonical" visibility span.

`C-h v org-show-context-detail RET` will show you the docstring for the variable, which is always a useful thing to do. You might want to experiment with different values of visibility spans for the various contexts.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found `org-reveal` in the org manual, but no mention of `org-show-context-detail`. Surprised this handy feature is hidden.